# Complex Integration (Error in my working)

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{5+4\sin\theta}$$ using complex analysis methods.

Upon using the standard substitutions, $\sin\theta=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$, $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$, the integral becomes

$$\int_C\frac{1}{2z^2+5iz-2}\,dz=\int_C\frac{1}{(z+\frac 12 i)(z+2i)}\,dz$$

Since the root that is in the unit circle is $-\frac 12 i$, we use the residue theorem to get

$2\pi i(\frac{1}{-0.5i+2i})=\frac 43 \pi$.

However the answer is $\frac 23 \pi$. Apparently, my answer is off by a factor of two, but upon checking I can't seem to find the error.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A factor $2$ is missing in the factorization of the denominator:
$$2z^2+5iz-2=2(z+\frac{i}{2})(z+2i).$$

Comment: i is missing in the first bracket